# Vega lite trend indicator

Tags: kibana, vega-lite

I am new to vega and kibana, and I am trying hard to build an indicator which shows the average monthly change of a field called 'Rating'. So far I was able to get the overal average of Rating, but I can't figure out how to get the current and the previous values so I could make a difference  between them. Ideally, if the monthly change goes up we would have a '+' or an upper triangle, and the opposite if it goes down. I can't share my data, but this is my code so far (where DATE is just a datetime field, and Rating are just scores):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"DATE": "2021-01-01", "Rating": 10},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-02", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-03", "Rating": 5},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-04", "Rating": 6},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-05", "Rating": 9},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-06", "Rating": 7},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-07", "Rating": 10},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-08", "Rating": 4},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-01", "Rating": 2},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-02", "Rating": 1},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-03", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021_02-04", "Rating": 5},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-05", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-06", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-01", "Rating": 2},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-02", "Rating": 1},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-03", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021_03-04", "Rating": 5},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-05", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-06", "Rating": 3}
    ]
  },
    "transform": [
    
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum['DATE'])", "as":"date"},
    {"timeUnit":"quarter", "field":"date", "as":"quarter_date"},
    {"joinaggregate":[{"op":"average", "field":"Rating", "as":"mean_rating_100"}],"groupby":["quarter_date"]}],
    
  "mark":{"type":"text","fontSize":30,"fontWeight":"bold","tooltip":true},
  "encoding":{
    "text":{
      "field":"mean_rating_100","aggregate":"average", "format":".1f"}}, 
 
 "config":{
  "legend":{"disable":true},
  "view":{"stroke":"transparent"}}
}
```

Any help will be more than welcome!
Thanks!

**Updated code:**

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoACIBBACoBRNCABMABjsBGfg9fvFIAEpqassjRnBwBfBVNLG3RHFzcPOy9fTH9A1AAOMIjrWxiPDwBmRL8AtDFMkHNs6Kc8twAWIuSS1AA2csqo+xq4tzFGlLQATnbInO73Nxb+5oB2Eaqu2ImHGenU4PnO3J6HNLW0Os2xpbs4-dQ7I+qTtwSlJIHUZyvF+LdC++LU-Jftp3rzmVwhVRtc3g4+p8mqkMsCOsdwVMoY8fnDQa93mdkc1DmiFn98rdzm08VtxoSHB8fF80KismSlhSGtj1qFSQjMRDzrD6RzKZNzj8ALphEAAdxoynoBwcDiU8BoZCwpVlSkwACckLIIAAzNjqhBGUDJBBwACqsjotgQcmlSiQBnQAFlbTAvDqaHBBMpbPDykgyGR1XxMHAjSA2DhrXAte7Pd7bA8SvbHSAkMRAiEhUog2wGDgmABPIwgF2yaUi4ES2TKNhi8OR2yCANxr0+9DpwIppsOzBmDMgLNKHWa01GZwKByV0BQHRQBjN0O2GgQABqOklAApVJgGAhKM2IH2MwBKAAEAH4z9u1HvKJ2zwBeZ9nnd3w-HsiXs8AHRABD-M9UGvN99wfAA+V9b33D9+y-K8-wAakA4C-34P8T3PVD-z-LwHVsZQaB1HVB2BWdBHnRcw3QUCD17OD+Fozs8NTQjiIScpyMotRqJUaC6KPODwKYgdu3QfNSJnOcFx4gj+NgjMAB4RK7NNWLreROOkqjlx1G9d33fMFAAckAPg3AE4d4yFCI-S71rMVZBM0zAG4dqyzMAXJ3jMwljbAgQsECYNhBA4sjtNkmj+L8gKgrsM9ELPYyEris8kCYCBbP3NidTsE8fPQUMj0HbMQGQdUAGs0GNQscF40MAA9MHdW0AGUaAAL2o-I5RAPVywAdTgRVlXQQKEzVNgguSKNUA1PRRTgWQoDYQjmmNOAGsqnr43bEACsa0Vi00La21sMs7V26reNkNgEH8HQvBNc1LUa9BCxjA1XVI3aJsEKbww9E7nU+8oAYTdAFMzYFQZ25iQe2giiJIrNRSW2QPVSUBBHIBb21AQiIFSrG0FmuBRWIT16yOo91TYMras1bUcCQYNy0HEIQiAA)

Answer (score 0):

I bet [`window` transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html) would be helpful on comparison between continuous data. You may share some dummy data via Vega Editor if more help is needed=)

Based on the further trial from @MTMM, I further simplify the `calculation`s. To get the last month record, I recommend `aggregation` of operation `argmax`  instead of `filter` because it is a bit more dynamic (in case you don't know the filtering criteria, and also treasure every opportunity to try something new~)

[2021-07-22 Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoACIBBACoBRNCABMABjsBGfg9fvFIAEpqassjRnBwBfBVNLG3RHFzcPOy9fTH9A1AAOMIjrWxiPDwBmRL8AtDFMkHNs6Kc8twAWIuSS1AA2csqo+xq4tzFGlLQATnbInO73Nxb+5oB2Eaqu2ImHGenU4PnO3J6HNLW0Os2xpbs4-dQ7I+qTtwSlJIHUZyvF+LdC++LU-Jftp3rzmVwhVRtc3g4+p8mqkMsCOsdwVMoY8fnDQa93mdkc1DmiFn98rdzm08VtxoSHB8fF80KismSlhSGtj1qFSQjMRDzrD6RzKZNzj8ALphEAAdxoynoBwcDiU8BoZCwpVlSkwACckLIIAAzNjqhBGUDJBBwACqsjotgQcmlSiQBnQAFlbTAvDqaHBBMpbPDykgyGR1XxMHAjSA2DhrXAte7Pd7bA8SvbHSAzMRAiEhUog2wGDgmABPIwgF2yaUi4ES2TKNhi8OR2yCANxr0+9DpwIp2wAGQdmE7ICzSh1mtNRmcCgcldAUB0UAYzdDtgAhDQIAA1HSSgAUqkwDAQlD7EAHGYAlAACAA+18v+8PlE7l4AvG-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)

[2021-07-21 Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoACIBBACoBRNCABMABjsBGfg9fvFIAEpqassjRnBwBfBVNLG3RHFzcPOy9fTH9A1AAOMIjrWxiPDwBmRL8AtDFMkHNs6Kc8twAWIuSS1AA2csqo+xq4tzFGlLQATnbInO73Nxb+5oB2Eaqu2ImHGenU4PnO3J6HNLW0Os2xpbs4-dQ7I+qTtwSlJIHUZyvF+LdC++LU-Jftp3rzmVwhVRtc3g4+p8mqkMsCOsdwVMoY8fnDQa93mdkc1LmiFn98rdzs88VtxoSHB8fF80KismSlhSGtjUkD6QjMRDzrD2WDOUjqdDaSEALphECYABOSFkEAAZmxJQgjKBkgg4ABVWR0WwIOT0LxIAzoACy+pgXjlNDggmUtnh5SQZDIkr4mDgKpAbBwurgMst1tttgeJSURtsSGIgVFShdbAYOCYAE8jCAzbIDWLgQB3fzKNjZz3e2yCJ0Bm129CRwJh40gUsQTBmKMgGMgOXS9VGZwKBxZ0BQHRQBil922GgQABqOhoygAFKpMAwEJQG02owBKAAEAH4twu1MvKNWtwBec9bxdHtfNsi7rcAHRABCfW9Q+6vK5PAD5L4eVzeUb3k+ADUr7vk+-BPhu24Qc+T6GnWyg0HKcqtiKSjIJKADWaCqkmOAeug7oAB6YJa+oAMo0AAXkR+QOEoCoZgA6nANBkFgthMGwQZKJgbC8ckPqoFKejinAshQGwyHNKqcBkXh7aBpWIDVoazquhQY5VqQ0pkB6TGKsg5HoJQzhoeKKaaMpFa2OmBrigJQk0CJxi2UGprmq2wJWnZ6CAdGvkqRGLblH5nkqChllZiA0myFaqSgII5CSZWoDIRASBMClaBiXA4rENahY2Y2kpsNhREStKso4EgroZq2IQhEAA)

Comment: Hi @hk7math, thanks for your reply. I already added some dummy data, but my problem persists. I also looked up the 'window transform' but still can't figure out how to get the mean rating of the previous minus the current month. I also look at [link](https://nyurik.github.io/Vega-Trends-Graph-for-Kibana/) and [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited) but with no joy! Again, any help is welcome!

Comment: I have added an editor based on your dummy data, the result is now shown in the tooltips (this is how I debug the transform usually :p)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! This is driving me insan for a couple of days!! After some tweeking I am almost there!! At this point I just need to be able to get the last value for march (just the value and the symbol), so I can use it only as an indicator in the dashboard. Could you please help me with is? [Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited)

Comment: @MTMM How are you doing? I add some further advice based on your attempt, see if it fits what you want? (tried to break down the calculations, but they can be condensed into one if you don't mind complex expression~)

Comment: oh wow!!! That was literally exactly was I was looking for!! I was actually trying to find a way to get the last value because when data comes in, it becomes a bit complicating to go every month and change the filter for the previous month, but like this the problem is solved (I guess?)! Also a very cool idea of showing the previous value and the monthly change! I really cannot thank you guys enough for your help!

Comment: My pleasure=) I also learnt a lot via problem solving~

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement I understand in here is that you want to calculate the previous minus current rating value. You can use a window transform where you can get the previous data. Since you are new to Vega-lite, you can view the data in the bottom part, there is a data_viewer section which will allow you to check the fields of data that gets generated via transformations (Screenshot of [data_viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccDlr.png))

Below is the sample snippet of a previous minus current values and also the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoACIBBACoBRNCABMABjsBGfg9fvFIAEpqassjRnBwBfBVNLG3RHFzcPOy9fTH9A1AAOMIjrWxiPDwBmRL8AtDFMkHNs6Kc8twAWIuSS1AA2csqo+xq4tzFGlLQATnbInO73Nxb+5oB2Eaqu2ImHGenU4PnO3J6HNLW0Os2xpbs4-dQ7I+qTtwSlJIHUZyvF+LdC++LU-Jftp3rzmVwhVRtc3g4+p8mqkMsCOsdwVMoY8fnDQa93mdkc1DmiFn98rdzm08VtxoSHB8fF80KismSlhSGtj1qFSQjMRDzrD6RzKZNzj8ALphEAAdxoynoBwcDiU8BoZCwpVlSkwACckLIIAAzNjqhBGUDJBBwACqsjotgQcmlSiQBnQAFlbTAvDqaHBBMpbPDykgyGR1XxMHAjSA2DhrXAte7Pd7bA8SvbHSAkMRAiEhUog2wGDgmABPIwgF2yaUi4ES2TKNhi8OR2yCANxr0+9DpwIppsOzBmDMgLNKHWa01GZwKByV0BQHRQBjN0O2GgQABqOklAApVJgGAhKM2IH2MwBKAAEAH4z9u1HvKJ2zwBeZ9nnd3w-HsiXs8AHRABD-M9UGvN99wfAA+V9b33D9+y-K8-wAakA4C-34P8T3PVD-z-LwHVsZQaB1HVB2BWdBHnRcw3QUCD17OD+Fozs8NTQjiIScpyMotRqJUaC6KPODwKYgdu3QfNSJnOcFx4gj+NgjMAB4RK7NNWLreROOkqjlx1G9d33fMFAAckAPg3AE4d4yFCI-S71rMVZBM0zAG4dqyzMAXJ3jMwljbAgQsECYNhBA4sjtNkmj+L8gKgrsM9ELPYyEris8kCYCBbP3NidTsE8fPQUMj0kkAuJkpd0BtcsYAAMX1ZBME3Cr6Ayygy3obyxL40MAElZFat1yg9QRQ3VNBQA9Ns5O63rXS8OAAEcGB0WwnSQdVYEHIcQGQdUAGtRpATBCxwXjQwAD0wd1bQAZRoAAvaj8jlEA9XLAB1OBFWVdBAoTNU2CC5Io1QDU9FFOBZCgNhCOaY04HO-bxoTfL9Au0Vi00Z743bUsZrVI7eNkNgEH8Ja1RoU0LStdBCxjA1cbTU6V325smC9R0dR0CA4DJqAdvZzm4BCUVMH+oaaCB4xMYm50ZoGrGe0Egc5eltMleBRHsaywdK2KuQPVSUBBHIcH21AQiIFSo20BBwWlGIT16wxo91TYHaTs1bUcFW8HUaFoA). You can try performing and get the mean rating on it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"DATE": "2021-01-01", "Rating": 10},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-02", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-03", "Rating": 5},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-04", "Rating": 6},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-05", "Rating": 9},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-06", "Rating": 7},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-07", "Rating": 10},
      {"DATE": "2021-01-08", "Rating": 4},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-01", "Rating": 2},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-02", "Rating": 1},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-03", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-04", "Rating": 5},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-05", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-02-06", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-01", "Rating": 4},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-02", "Rating": 6},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-03", "Rating": 3},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-04", "Rating": 10},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-05", "Rating": 8},
      {"DATE": "2021-03-06", "Rating": 3}
    ]
  },
  "width": 400,
  "height": 500,
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "month", "as": "Month", "field": "DATE"},
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "mean", "field": "Rating", "as": "avg"}],
      "groupby": ["Month"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "lag", "field": "avg", "as": "lastAvg"}],
      "frame": [1, 0]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "isValid(datum.lastAvg) ? (datum.avg === datum.lastAvg ? \"/\" : (datum.avg > datum.lastAvg ? \"+\" : \"-\")) : \"/\"",
      "as": "diff"
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.lastAvg-datum.avg", "as": "diff2"},
    {"calculate": "datum.lastAvg>datum.avg", "as": "up"},
    {"calculate": "datum.lastAvg<datum.avg", "as": "down"},
    {
      "calculate": "if(datum.up,'',if(datum.down,'',''))",
      "as": "symbol2"
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.symbol2 + ' ' + abs(datum.diff2)", "as": "test"},
    {"calculate": "monthFormat(month(datum.Month))", "as": "dateInMonth"},
    {"filter": {"field": "dateInMonth", "equal": "March"}}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fontSize": 30,
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "tooltip": true
  },
  "encoding": {
    "text": {"field": "test"},
    "y": {
      "field": "Month",
      "type": "nominal",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
      "axis": {"labels": false, "ticks": false}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Month"},
      {"field": "lastAvg"},
      {"field": "avg"},
      {"field": "diff"}
    ]
  },
  "config": {"legend": {"disable": true}, "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the monthly average requirement. The data viewer technique is useful when trialing in the editor, but I'm sometimes lazy and probe via tooltip directly at my working place

Comment: Hi @wahab, memon, first of all thank you for your help. Second, and regarding "the example provided in question does not show much efforts", I honestly find it a bit offensive, mainly because I have no knowledge about the vega syntax, and being able to get a result, was already an achievement for me. So please respect the efforts and level of knowledge of the people that come here for support.

Comment: @MTMM sorry I didn't meant to offend you. Yes, you already mentioned that you are new to it, so its understandable. But as I mentioned we also have limit to our support as well. Also appreciate your efforts (Better to delete my offensive comment).

Comment: Anything else you want to ask regarding the answer then feel free.

Comment: @wahab memon, I am also sorry, maybe I was a bit aggressive but vega has been really a struggle for me, and I am really tired!! So yes, I have a (hopefully) final question regarding this issue. I need to get only the last value, and present it like a card in a dashboard. So if you go to my updated [Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited), I only need to have the value for march (with the arrow, no month, like a card) to let the user know if the monthly change increased or decreased. Again, I am sorry if I went a bit too far, and thank you for the support.

Comment: The link you provided does not open up the proper chart. You are mostly sharing your url visible in your browser, which will not work us. There is a 'share' button on the toolbar of your editor, click on it a popup will appear. Select option 'copy link to clipboard', which will copy link on its own. Then paste that link over here (the link is quite long), with that we will be able to access your editor chart.

Comment: @wahabmemon, I tried but the url is too long. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can add that link in your question as it will support lengthy strings, so it will be useful for others as well while referring to it.

Comment: Saw your editor, you only need to remove the specific march label text right ?

Comment: @wahab memon No, I need to keep only that one, so just stay with the arrow and the value (2.0000...), if possible. Thanks again!

Comment: yes it was possible, applied a filter transform which will just filter out the month `March` and removed axis labels. Refer updated answer above

Comment: @wahab memon a filter!! Of course! Oh, thank you soo much!!!!!